# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, leakcanary, android-api-33

I changed the API targeting of my app to 33 and when I try to run it I get this error:

[image]

This is my manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sekiztik.words">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
        android:name="com.sekiztik.words.presentation.common.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/fmn_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".presentation.common.mainactivity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
            android:name="com.sekiztik.words.presentation.screen.player.service.PlayerService"
            android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I tried:

- Running on emulator and a real device, no difference

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest version of LeakCanary.